# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

I want to query a database using sqlalchemy and pandas. My items that I have to pass to the where clause have singe quotes and I could not figure out how to resolve it. Below, sample code and the error message.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxx:5439/data_base')
items = ('fish', 'cow', "fish's")
items = tuple(item.replace("'", "''") for item in items) # replace one single quote by two single quotes

query_string = """
  select * from my_table
  where item in {items}
""".format(items = items)

df = pd.read_sql(query_string, engine)
```

> (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "fish''''s" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the double quotes by single quotes in the final query_string resolved my problem.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('postgresql://xxx:5439/data_base')
items = ('fish', 'cow', "fish's")
items = tuple(item.replace("'", "''") for item in items) # replace one single quote by two single quotes

query_string = """
  select * from my_table
  where item in {items}
""".format(items = items)

query_string = query_string.replace('"', "'")

df = pd.read_sql(query_string, engine)
```